# How to call method "continue" without crash Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I'm using pod AWSCore, and, in this pod, have a method called `continue` in class `AWSTask`.

I need call this method, but, if I try call this method, Xcode crash, and it think this is a builtin `continue`, instead of a method `continue`.

[image]

How to fix it? And, yes, [I already open a issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/539).

Comment: you need to handle exception for this

Comment: @ShobhakarTiwari Sorry, but how? I did not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please use the following block of code and check if it still crashes?

```
let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
let request = AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest()
// set request object values as desired
transferManager?.download(request).continue({ task -> Any? in
    if let error = task.error {
        print("\(error)")
    }

    if let result = task.result {
        print("\(result)")
    }

    return nil
})
```

Thanks,
Rohan

Comment: +1: It looks like `AWSTask.continue` takes a block that returns `id` in ObjC, which means that in Swift you need a closure that returns `Any` (or `Any?` depending on the surrounding nullability annotation), not a closure that returns `Void`.

Comment: It's work! Thank you! The code became a bit ugly, because it needs to return something that will never be used (`nil`, always), but it is the only solution... Much thank.